# EditText com reticências

Tags: android, android-layout

No EditText,

quando o texto não puder ser exibido completamente e perder o foco,

tem alguma tag que possa ser setada para que ele exiba o texto com reticências?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer dessa forma no XML

```
<EditText
        ...
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

E ai você precisa colocar no Java

```
String text = edit_text.getText().toString();

if(text.length() > 8){
   edit_text.setText(text.substring(0, 8) + "...");
}
```

Com isso se ele ficar maior que 8 caracteres vai colocar o ... no fim

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar, o tipo de layout que o edit está inserido faz direrença?

Comment: Editei minha resposta com alguns complementos, não tinha visto que o outro método que te passei foi descontinuado pelo Google

Comment: Como faço para saber em que posição devo truncar o texto para que o resultado (contando com ...) fique na área visível do EditText?

Comment: Vai colocando caracteres no text="" do XML até reparar que chegou no fim, foi a coisa mais "inteligente" que consegui pensar

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if(view.hasFocus()){
                    // se tá com foco, então pôe os "..." no texto
                } else {
                    // se tá sem foco, então mostra o texto inteiro
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Eu preciso ter as reticências no texto quando o edit fica sem o foco para indicar que o texto não está totamente visível.